# Sticky Header Listview section is running position and missing

Tags: android, android-listview, sticky

[image]
[image]
As you can see the Section Header is running when I scroll the listview. What is the problem?

```
private void Setup() {
    groupListView.setDrawingListUnderStickyHeader(true);

    groupListView.setAreHeadersSticky(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed.

I updated my library to latest build and now it works.